# categorize sentence based on words in sentence for multiple sentences

Tags: python, list

```
data = ["my web portal is not working","online is better than offline", "i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines"]
words = ["web", "online"]
```

I want to iterate over sentences and check if any of words present in list words. If yes I want a single category for each sentence else category "other". It is working if I am giving single word from the words list, but I want to check all words in single run.

```
b = []
def ch_1(x,y):
    for i in x:
        if y in i:
            b.append("web")
        else:
            b.append("others")
    return b
```

Getting error :

> in ' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: Take list of sentences. Make list of words either "web" or "other" per sentence depending on if they contain any of words in another list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [in operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) to check string 'contains' substring.

```
data = ["my web portal is not working","online is better than offline", "i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines"]
words = ["web", "online"]

def ch_1(x,y):
    b = []
    for i in x:
        web = False
        for j in y:
            if j in i:
                web = True
                break
        if web:
            b.append("web")
        else:
            b.append("others")
    return b

print(ch_1(data,words))
```

O/P:

```
['web', 'web', 'others']
```

Comment: Output should be [web,web,others]

Comment: @anant Have you tried my code, the output will be same as you expected

Answer (score 1):

This code is suitable for any number of words in `words` and sentences in `data`:

```
data = [
    "my web portal is not working",
    "online is better than offline",
    "i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines"
]

words = ["web", "online"]


def ch_1(words, data):
    categories = {sentence: [] for sentence in data}
    for sentence in data:
        for word in words:
            if word in sentence:  # and categories[sentence] == [] ((if you want exactly one category for each sentence))
                categories[sentence].append(word)
    for sentence in categories:
        if categories[sentence] == []:
            categories[sentence].append('others')
    return categories

print(ch_1(words, data))
```

> ```
> {
> 'i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines': ['others'],
> 'online is better than offline': ['online'],
> 'my web portal is not working': ['web']
> }
> ```

Comment: Slight difference in the output needed. It should be web, web, others

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through both the lists given as parameters.

```
def ch_1(x,y):
    b = []
    for i in x:
        for j in y:
            if j in i:
                b.append('web')
                break
        else:
            b.append('others')
    return b
print(ch_1(data, words))
```

**Output**

```
['web', 'web', 'others']
```

Comment: I want single category for each sentence i.e. output should be [web,web,others]

Comment: I have tried that but the same error/confusion. Output should be [web,web,others] as first two sentences have words web/online. Can you please check

Comment: @anant It shouldn't. It is working for me. I even tried `data = ["my web portal is not working","online is better than offline", "i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines", "test web" , 'test online', 'test nothing']` it's giving `['web', 'web', 'others', 'web', 'web', 'others']` as output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Actually I have tries that but did'nt used break. Thanks :)

Comment: What would be the change in code if i have more than one lists to check from. For e.g. words_2 = ['apple']. so if sentence has 'apple' in it category will be fruits. So there are now three categories i.e. Web, Fruits, Others

Comment: @anant Hi, you may post this as a separate question. Hint : create a dictionary with keys as `'web' `, `'fruits' ` and corresponding values as the the list. You will have to then loop through this dictionary with `dict_.items()`; if found append the key in new list otherwise append `'others'`.

Comment: ok what I understand you are saying to make dictionary like dictio = {'fruits':['apple'], 'web': ['web', 'online']} and loop through dictionary to get the desired category. but can you help me understand the code for it please

Answer (score 0):

In your statement

```
if y in i:
```

y is a list. You don't show how you called ch_1, but I'm assuming you used ch_1(data, words). The parameter y is therefore ["web", "online"], and you are trying to find the whole list in i, which is a string. So you get the message

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

because it expect y to be a string to find in string i. Providing it with a list doesn't make sense. If you used y[0] in i, or y[1] in i, then you would be correctly providing a string to find in i.

Comment: You are right, when I was providing y[0] in i I was getting correct output, but my problem is that I have long list of words. I cant provide y[index] for number of times. Any solution for that

Comment: Try, if any(a in i for a in y): I also recommend you try to come up with meaningful variable names.

Comment: Used any not working. Solution provided by @Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev worked. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try form of `[conditional expression for sentence in data]`:

```
data = [
    "my web portal is not working",
    "online is better than offline",
    "i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines",
]
words = ["web", "online"]

["web" if any(word in sentence for word in words) else "others" for sentence in data]
```